# Combining itemQuantity and deviceCategory in Google Analytics API query

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've recently come across some odd results when pulling out Google Analytics data using the Google Analytics API. The combination of the eCommerce metric 'ga:itemQuantity' with the dimension 'ga:deviceCategory' seems to induce GA to truncate the date range of my request, resulting in incomplete counts for other metrics like sessions, transactions, and revenue. Image with my report configuration (in Google Sheets - also tested in Google Query Explorer with the same results):

[image]

This only seems to apply to a certain view, with an identical request generating correct counts (when compared to the web interface) in another view for the same property.

When I switch deviceCategory for other dimensions like channelGrouping, the request returns correct results.

When I remove the itemQuantity metric, the request returns correct results for other metrics like sessions, transactions, and revenue.

Sampling is not applied in any of the scenarios I investigated.

Has anyone encountered similar inconsistencies?

Comment: Did you check the same with custom reports in Google Analytics?

Comment: How do you know that the issue is not the result of sampling?

Comment: @dikesh - I checked the same report in the Google Analytics web interface, and this gives me more correct figures (i.e. higher totals and data across my entire date range)

Comment: @DalmTo - in the resulting report within Google Sheets, the field "Contains Sampled Data" is set to "No".

Comment: This can be bug with addon. You should check the output with Google Query Explorer to check whether GA is the cause of the problem or the addon.

Comment: @dikesh - good idea, thanks. Will report back with Query Explorer results.

Comment: OK, I checked in Google Query Explorer and it looks as though this could be a problem with the Google Analytics query itself, rather than the Google Sheets add-on. Removing ga:itemQuantity from my query more than doubles my sessions when using ga:deviceCategory as the dimension. With ga:channelGrouping as the dimension, session counts are exactly the same with and without ga:itemQuantity. For all of these queries, the date range, etc. are consistent and the response says that sampled data was not used.